# Is the formula $[k(a,b):k][k(a) \cap k(b):k] = [k(a):k][k(b):k]$ true for simple algebraic extensions ($k(a)/k$ and $k(b)/k$ )?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $k$ be any field and $L/k$ be a field extension. Suppose $a, b \in L$ are algebraic over $k$. Is the formula  $[k(a,b):k][k(a) \cap k(b):k] = [k(a):k][k(b):k]$ true?

This formula comes from page 228 (Remark 2.4) in "An invitation to Arithmetic Geometry" by Prof. Dino Lorenzini. But the author didn't explain why this formula is true. Thank you for four answer.

Comment: Some discussion is contained in [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/816592/11619). It is not an exact duplicate, so I won't cast my abstract-algebra powervote.

Comment: Search for *linearly disjoint extensions* in [Pete L. Clark's lecture notes](http://math.uga.edu/~pete/FieldTheory.pdf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is false. Consider $k=\Bbb{Q}$, $a=\root3\of2$, $b=e^{2\pi i/3}a$. We have $[k(a,b):k]=6$, $k(a)\cap k(b)=k$ and $[k(a):k]=[k(b):k]=3$.

Comment: I will delete this, if we find a good duplicate. I have used this example myself a few times here, but the motivating context has been a bit different.

Comment: Oh! I see! Thank you very much! (so... I think I need to find another way to correct my note...)

Comment: @Peter the formula does hold if you know that $k(a)$ and $k(b)$ are both Galois over $k$.

Comment: But the formula $[k(a,b):k][k(a) \cap k(b):k] \leq [k(a):k][k(b):k]$ is true. Right? (by my computation...)

Comment: Correct, @PeterHu. That is a consequence of the inequality
$$[k(a,b):k(a)]\le [k(b):k]$$ that is a simple onsequence of the fact that the minimal polynomial of $b$ over $k(a)$ is a factor of the minimal polynomial of $b$ over $k$.