# Dimension of compositum of two fields, one of them Galois.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Let $L, K, F = L \cap K$ be fields such that $[L:F] , [K:F] < \infty$. $LK$ is defined as the compositum of the two fields(shortest field containing $K$ and $L$ in some algebraic closure).

Also, assume hat $L$ is Galois. Then, I can prove that $[L:F][K:F] = [LK:F]$ assuming that $L = F[\theta]$ using something like the primitive element theorem.

Does the result hold in more generality($L \neq F[\theta])$ and how does one prove it?

Comment: Not clear what your “more general” statement would look like. If neither field is Galois over $F$, you certainly don’t have that relationship.

Comment: I meant without the conditions for the primitive element theorem holding, sorry!

Comment: Chiming in with Lubin. The standard counterexample is $L=\Bbb{Q}(\root3\of2)$, $K=\Bbb{Q}(\omega\root3\of2)$ where $\omega$ is a primitive third root of unity. Because $p(x)=x^3-2$ is irreducible $[L:F]=3=[K:F]$, but $LK$ is the splitting field of $p(x)$, so $[LK:F]=6$.

Comment: I have clarified, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: The concept you are looking for is *linearly disjoint extensions*. If you can locate for example Pete L. Clark's lecture notes (on University of Georgia webpages, sorry I don't have the link), there is more extensive information there.

Comment: Check out [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/381775/11619). Looks like you want to talk there.

Comment: Thanks, that link seems to be exactly what I am looking for. I thought the question would be a lot simpler than it now looks!