# Isomorphism between Algebraic Field Extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field, ring-isomorphism

Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be two linearly independent algebraic numbers. Is it always true that $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta) \cong \mathbb{Q}(\alpha + \beta)$?

Certainly $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha + \beta) \subset\mathbb{Q}(\alpha, \beta)$. The tricky thing is showing the reverse inclusion.

Let $\deg(\alpha) = m$ and $\deg(\beta) = n$ then $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta)$ has dimension $mn$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. My thought here is that you can take successive powers of $\alpha + \beta$ and generate a system of equations. For some sufficient power, the matrix of coefficients will be solvable. With that, you can isolate $\alpha$ and $\beta$ which proves the reverse inclusion.

Does anyone have any insights?

Comment: I like the thought about taking powers of $\alpha + \beta$. My concern is that a generic term will look like $\begin{pmatrix}n \\ k\end{pmatrix} \alpha^{n - k}\beta^k$, which a priori has no reason to belong to $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha + \beta)$, so with each equation you're expanding the list of variables you'll need to solve for.

Comment: No. Consider $\alpha=\root3\of2$ and $\beta=\omega\alpha$. We have $\alpha+\beta=-\omega^2\alpha$. Here $[\Bbb{Q}(\alpha+\beta):\Bbb{Q}]=3$ and $[\Bbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta):\Bbb{Q}]=6$. Note also that here $m=n=3$ and $6<mn=9$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, I was trying to avoid those cases. Linearly independent wasn't the right condition. What if $m$ and $n$ are different?

Comment: It seems to me that the concept you want is *linearly disjoint*. $[\Bbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta):\Bbb{Q}]=mn$ is equivalent to $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$ and $\Bbb{Q}(\beta)$ being linearly disjoint extensions. For this to happen it is obviously necessary (but as the above example shows not sufficient) that $\Bbb{Q}(\beta)\cap\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)=\Bbb{Q}$. (assuming both are seen as subfields of a common umbrella field like $\Bbb{C}$ so that it makes sense to talk about their intersection).

Comment: (cont'd) If both $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$ and $\Bbb{Q}(\beta)$ are Galois over $\Bbb{Q}$, then the above necessary condition is also sufficient. See [this post by Pete L. Clark](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/381775/11619) for more, not the least for a link to his nice set of lecture notes.

Comment: (cont'd) If both extensions are Galois and intersect trivially, then it easily follows that $\alpha+\beta$ generates the composition (and that the composition has the predicted degree). Otherwise it depends. The assumption of $m$ and $n$ being different leaves open possibilities like $\alpha=\root4\of2$, $\beta=\sqrt2$. In that case actually $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta)=\Bbb{Q}(\alpha+\beta)$, but also clearly $\Bbb{Q}(\beta)\subset\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$.

Comment: Thank you @JyrkiLahtonen. I'm also a big fan of Dr. Clark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\alpha=\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}$ and $\beta=\sqrt{2}$.  Then $$\mathbb{Q}(\alpha+\beta)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})\neq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta).$$

Of course the primitive element theorem tells you that for all but finitely many $c\in \mathbb{Q}$, $$\mathbb{Q}(\alpha+c\beta)=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta).$$

Comment: I was trying to avoid these situations, where you luck out with a cancellation. Maybe having them be linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q(\alpha,\beta)}$ would make it more interesting. But thank you for the theorem, I will be looking into that.

Comment: $\alpha,\beta$ will always be linearly dependant over $\mathbb{Q}(a,b)$ as they lie in a $1$--dimensional vector space.

Comment: Touche. Do you see what I'm after though?

Comment: Yes - from @JyrkiLahtonen's comments, it looks like the linear independence that you want in your question is for the $\{\alpha^i\beta^j|\,\,i=0,1,2,\cdots,n-1, j= 0,1,2,\cdots,m-1\}$ to be linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$.  Here $n,m$ are the degrees of the minimal polynomials of $\alpha,\beta$ respectively.   Perhaps you should ask if this linear independence guarantees that $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha+\beta)=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta)$, in a new question, and link it to this one.