# Compositum of Galois extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, cyclic-groups

Suppose $p,q$ are distinct primes. $K_1$ is a Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}(\mu_{pq})$ of degree $p$, $K_1 \subseteq \mathbb{C}$. $K_2$ is a Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}(\mu_{pq})$ of degree $q$, $K_2 \subseteq \mathbb{C}$. Let $L$ be the compositum of $K_1$ and $K_2$ in $\mathbb{C}$.

I could not figure out the reasoning behind this argument: ($p$, $q$) = 1, $K_1 \cap K_2 = \mathbb{Q}(\mu_{pq})$, so $Gal(L/\mathbb{Q}(\mu_{pq}))$ $\cong$  $C_p$ × $C_q$ $\cong$  $C_{pq}$. Why is $Gal(L/\mathbb{Q}(\mu_{pq}))$ $\cong$  $C_p$ × $C_q$? Maybe there's a theorem regarding this but I can't remember.

Comment: The concept you are missing is that of *linearly disjoint extension*. A general result is that two Galois extensions with a trivial intersection have a compositum that is Galois, and the Galois group is the direct product. For a thorough introduction to the topic see [Pete L. Clarks Lecture notes on field theory](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/FieldTheory.pdf). You want Chapter 12 in particular., or [his more refined question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/381775/11619). For a quick'n-dirty intro, my [first-aid seminar notes](https://users.utu.fi/lahtonen/linearly_disjoint.pdf) may help.